# bigquery UNION ALL on different struct schema table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

In the BigQuery Table of GA4, because it's possible to customize fields, the schema of structures like
`items[TYPE: RECORD]` 
. I want to UNION ALL multiple GA4 Tables under different accounts. However, due to the issue mentioned above, it's causing difficulties for me to UNION them.
EX the error message:

**analytics_xxxxxxxx5**

| event | items.item_name | items.items_params |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t5e1 | t5i1 | t5a |
| t5e2 | t5i2 | t5b |

**analytics_xxxxxxxx6**

| event | items.item_name |
| --- | --- |
| t6e1 | t6i1 |
| t6e2 | t6i2 |

```
SELECT event,items
FROM `analytics_xxxxxxxx5`
UNION ALL
SELECT event,items
FROM `analytics_xxxxxxxx6`
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**:

```
UNION ALL has incompatible types: STRUCT<item_id STRING, item_name STRING, item_brand STRING, ...>, STRUCT<item_id STRING, item_name STRING, item_brand STRING, ...>
```

**My expecting:**

| event | items.item_name | items.items_params |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t5e1 | t5i1 | t5a |
| t5e2 | t5i2 | t5b |
| t6e1 | t6i1 | null |
| t6e2 | t6i2 | null |

Comment: Could you edit your question and add tables definitions ? also tag only the RDBMS you are using !

Answer (score 0):

Union and thus combining struct of different types is not possible. Convert the struct to JSON and then union the tables.

```sql
SELECT event,to_json(items)
FROM `analytics_xxxxxxxx5`
UNION ALL
SELECT event,to_json(items)
FROM `analytics_xxxxxxxx6`
```

I would suggest to extract the relevant data from the JSON by a functionm which returns the needed items in a struct.

```sql
create temp function extracting(A any type) as 
(
  struct(a.name,
  a['nil'],
 a.item
  )
);

Select 1 as a, extracting(to_json( struct("1a" as name)))
union all
Select 2 as a, extracting(to_json( struct("1a" as name,5 as nil, "x" as item)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Google added a field `item_params` into `items` RECORD in these tables without any warning ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItZ6l.png)). So they broke their own schema and different shards of `events_*` can't be concatenated now. As I see, the change was made on October 23. And no, this change is not reflected in official documentation: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en#
You need manually adjust schemas of tables in your query now.

Comment: Rather than linking to an image, could you embed that information as a table and or textually like in the question?